# FCM Token is shorter than it was a while ago

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Did someone discover a change in push tokens from FCM lately? I discovered more and more problems with FCM. The push does not arrive on the devices. I discovered that the push tokens are much shorter than the last time I checked it. The used to be about 160 characters and are now about 22 characters

This is a token I received -> fUXVtRw_SBgkCSflBw32wx (changed a few characters)

I fetch them via

```
FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().id.addOnCompleteListener{ task ->
    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
        Timber.d("%s getInstanceId failed", LOG_TAG)
        return@addOnCompleteListener
    }

    // Get new Instance ID token
    val token = task.result
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id you get from `FirebaseInstallations` is not a push token but as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/installations/FirebaseInstallations#getId()) states

> [...]a globally unique identifier of this Firebase app installation

You can acquire a push token either by using `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token`

Or storing the token you get in the `onNewToken` callback of your `FirebaseMessagingService` somewhere, for example shared preferences.